Evaluation of sum of product of dirichlet characters
An Analytic number theory question:
Let, $\chi_{0,q_2}$ be the trivial character modulo $q_2$ and $rad(q)$ be the radical of $q$.
I need to estimate the summation below:
$$S_1=\sum\limits_{\substack{q_1,q_2\in N\\q_1q_2=rad(q)}}|\sum\limits_{|x_1|,|x_2|\leq N}\left(\frac{\alpha_1x_1^2+a_2x_2^2}{q_1}\right)\chi_{0,q_2}(\alpha_1x_1^2+\alpha_2x_2^2)|^2$$
where, $\left(\frac{.}{q_1}\right)$ is the Legendre symbol which is a Dirichlet character mod $q_1$. Eventually I need to estimate $S_1$. There is a result:
$$\sum_{|x_1|,|x_2|\leq N}\left(\frac{\alpha_1x_1^2+\alpha_2x_2^2}{q}\right)\ll q^{\epsilon}N^{\left(2-\frac{1}{r}\right)}q^\frac{(r_1+2)}{4r_1^2}$$
provided that $q^{1/4+1/2r_1}\leq N \leq q^{5/12+1/2r_1}$ and $r\geq 3$. Can we use this result (Theorem 3 of the paper) to estimate the following:
$$\sum\limits_{|x_1|,|x_2|\leq N}\left(\frac{\alpha_1x_1^2+a_2x_2^2}{q_1}\right)\chi_{0,q_2}(\alpha_1x_1^2+\alpha_2x_2^2).$$ Any idea is always welcome.
